# DataTables global Regex Search in each column

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'd like to implement a feature, where you can start your search string with `$` to get a startsWith search in all searchable columns.
This is what I've tried so far:

```
$('#myinput').on('keyup', (event) => {
    let searchValue = $(event.currentTarget).val();        
    if (searchValue.startsWith('$')) {
        searchValue = `^${searchValue.substr(1)}`;
    }
    this.dataTable.search(searchValue, true, false, false).draw();
});
```

But apparently, this only searches in the first column. If I don't use `^` in my search, it searches all columns. How can I check if any of the columns start with `myValue` instead of the entire row data?

Can be reproduced on https://datatables.net/examples/api/regex.html.
Enable global Regex and search ^Airi and after that ^Accountant.

You will get results for Airi, but not for Accountant.

How can I make the search for `^Accountant` still display the first entry, as the second column starts with Accountant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because when global regex is set to `true` it will treat the whole row as text. Therefore your search should look like:

```js
$('#myinput').on('keyup', (event) => {
    let searchValue = $(event.currentTarget).val();        
    if (searchValue.startsWith('$')) {
        searchValue = `\b${searchValue.substr(1)}`;
    }
    this.dataTable.search(searchValue, true, false, false).draw();
});
```

Regex token `\b` stands for "boundary". Each start of a word creates a new boundary (here is the Regex spec: https://regex101.com/r/s0MdwW/1). You can also try how it works in the Datatables website by searching "\bTok" which should make "Airi" appear.

Note however that there is a catch: Searching for "Sat" will match "Airi Satou" since there is a boundary between the words. If you want to avoid that particular case then you would <strike>simply need to perform a `^` regex search (like your current code) but *for each column*</strike>, and then collect all results. Per column regex search only use the column content for the match:

[image]

---

Update: Ok so the per column search was definitively more complex than expected because simply searching  each column would create an AND search. For example searching for "Airi" would also require that "Airi" is in *all* other columns.

To solve this particular a custom search function must be built. Here you can find it: https://codepen.io/adelriosantiago/pen/XWKGoLx?editors=1011

This custom function OR searches through the columns using the `$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push` function.

Comment: thanks for the answer! Can you summarize how to perform a per column search?

Comment: @TomM I have updated the answer with an example how to do it.

Comment: I tried the column-search too but for me it just straight up cleared the entire table regardless of my search string. Used the custom search filter `$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push` you suggested too and could solve my problem with that, so I'll accept your answer. Thank you!